# What are firebase dependencies for appcompact-v7:25.3.1

Tags: android, firebase, dependencies

I keep getting errors when I try to sync my gradle. It has something to do with the SDK version. I would like to know which firebase dependcies fit to 25.3.1

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})


compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
//compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:1.0.2'
//compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.5.2'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.2.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **`10.2.1`** and **`1.2.0`** version .

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
```

**Clean-Rebuild** and **Run** .

> // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
>   // the
>   latest Google Repository in the Android SDK manager

Comment: "Error:Failed to resolve: com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.0"   It then gives me this error, any idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41659272/errorfailed-to-resolve-com-twitter-sdk-androidtwitter2-3-0-android-studio

Comment: Thanks mate it did a successful build

Comment: can you post the documentation link or as to how to know which version is compatible with which version.