# All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification for 26.+ (android version 2.3.3)

Tags: android

I am new in Android development, I am making Firebase chatting app, But suddenly I am facing the issue of transitive dependency. I followed this link 
[Do not use + for a library version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581963/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version/42582204#42582204) . But failed to resolve the problem. Here is my code build.gradle(Module),

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "kiran.example.com.firebasechattingapp21_11"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.1.1'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I am facing the following error,

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 26.0.0-alpha1, 25.1.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.0-alpha1 and
>   com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0

Following is the code of build.gradle (Project)

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

If anyone is having the solution please help.

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.0'
compile  'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0'

add these in gradle and it will fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes after searching I Solved this issue by the following way

I added the following lines in build.gradle app level

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.1.1'
    **//add the following for transitive dependency**
    compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

after that I solved the problem which I have posted here, But one new problem occured i.e.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>
> > Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@supportsRtl value=(true) from AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-35    is also present at
> >     [com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.1.1] AndroidManifest.xml:14:18-45
> >     value=(false).    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"'
> >     to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-22:19 to override.

By taking the reference from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095703/manifest-merger-failed-error) I solved above new issue. Thanks for your comments. :-)

Answer (score 0):

> change this

```
 compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
```

> to

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2-alpha1'
```

**As stated these versions must be same to**

> buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

Answer (score 0):

change below lines from app level gradle file.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
```

Comment: thanks for your help but getting an error Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@supportsRtl value=(true) from AndroidManifest.xml:10:9-35
 is also present at [com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.1.1] AndroidManifest.xml:14:18-45 value=(false).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-19:19 to override.

Comment: can you please add `tools:replace="android.supportsRtl"` to your AndroidManifest.xml file inside application tag. Also add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` to your manifest tag. Remove `tools:replace="android.supportRtl"` line from application tag.

Comment: adding and then again removing is giving the same error

Comment: it was my bad. I was about to say that remove `android:supportsRtl="true"` this line from application tag. add `tools:replace="android.supportsRtl"` line to application tag.

Comment: giving the manifest merging error Merging Errors: Error: tools:replace specified at line:6 for attribute tools:android.supportsRtl, but no new value specified app main manifest (this file), line 5 Error: Validation failed, exiting app main manifest (this file)

Comment: Can you please remove `tools:replace="android.supportsRtl"` and `android:supportsRtl="true"` lines and check once?

Comment: I solved this by adding xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
Add this to <application/>

tools:node="replace"  thanks for your help

Comment: It was mentioned in previous comments.. I thought you did still you are facing issues.. Now your issue resolved or not yet?

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to build.gradle file

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}
```

and then change

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
```

Comment: thanks for the help but getting the same error with the message failed to resolve com.twitter.sdk.android 2.3.0

Comment: solved com.twitter.sdk.android 2.3.0 related issue by this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41659272/errorfailed-to-resolve-com-twitter-sdk-androidtwitter2-3-0-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

This version should match with each other

```
FirebaseUI Version  Firebase/Play Services Version

    3.1.0   11.4.2
    3.0.0   11.4.2
    2.4.0   11.4.0
    2.3.0   11.0.4
    2.2.0   11.0.4
    2.1.1   11.0.2
    2.0.1   11.0.1
    1.2.0   10.2.0
    1.1.1   10.0.0 or 10.0.1
    1.0.1   10.0.0 or 10.0.1
    1.0.0   9.8.0
```

You versions are matching with each other i suggest you to upgrade versions like.

```
Firebase ui - 2.3.0  // firebase/play services -11.0.4
```

Comment: thanks for the help but I have already done in my post (for firebase 10.0.1) compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.1.1'